# Can't assign a variable to the desired memory location

Tags: assembly, x86-16, memory-address, emu8086, memory-segmentation

I'm new to assembly. I'm trying to move some numbers into the memory locatons starting from `0800:0010` but couldn't figure it out.
Here's the code:

```
.data    
    NUM0 DB 00H
    NUM1 DB 22H
    NUM2 DB 00H
    NUM3 DB 35H
    NUM4 DB 71H
    NUM5 DB 03H
.code            
    MOV AX, 0800H
    MOV DS, AX
    
    MOV AX, 0010H
    MOV ES, AX
    
    MOV DS:[0010], NUM1
    MOV DS:[0011], NUM2
    MOV DS:[0012], NUM3
    MOV DS:[0013], NUM4
    MOV DS:[0014], NUM5
```

The code gives an error:

> (15) wrong parameters: `MOV   [0000], NUM1`

So, I tried an alternative code:

```
.data    
    NUM0 DB 00H
    NUM1 DB 22H
    NUM2 DB 00H
    NUM3 DB 35H
    NUM4 DB 71H
    NUM5 DB 03H
.code            
    MOV AX, 0800H
    MOV DS, AX
    
    MOV AX, 0010H
    MOV ES, AX
    
    MOV AL, NUM1
    MOV DS:[0010], AL
    MOV AL, NUM2
    MOV DS:[0011], AL
    MOV AL, NUM3
    MOV DS:[0012], AL
    MOV AL, NUM4
    MOV DS:[0013], AL
    MOV AL, NUM5
    MOV DS:[0014], AL
```

This does not give any error but my desired memory location, 0800:0010 is empty. Also, even though `NUM0` is useless, if I don't include it, the `NUM1` is changed into 57H. When I include it, the problem seems to go away.
Also, it looks like the DS register seems to start at `0100` then go to `0000` after the line `MOV DS, AX`.

Comment: Why are you trying to store to `0000` to `0004` while you want to store to `0010`?

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT, fixed the locations it but the issues remain.

Comment: Shouldn't the `0010` be `0010H`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError is it? Tried it but didn't solved the issues.

Comment: In `0800:0010` the first word (`0800`) is a segment value and you correctly loaded it into DS, *but the second word (`0010`) is an offset value and you should never load that in a segment register like ES*.

Comment: @SepRoland yep I saw that now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

`MOV AL, NUM1` in most assemblers tries to load the **offset** of the byte labeled `NUM1` (which is 1). If you want to load the **contents** of this byte, it's always better to write `MOV AL,[NUM1]`. Such instruction loads register `AL` from the memory labeled `NUM1`, and uses default segment register `DS` for memory addressing, because no segment override was specified. Alas, your register `DS` is not initialized to point at `.data` segment where `NUM1` resides.
Try another alternative:

```
.data    
    NUM0 DB 00H
    NUM1 DB 22H
    NUM2 DB 00H
    NUM3 DB 35H
    NUM4 DB 71H
    NUM5 DB 03H
.code            
    MOV AX, .data ; or whichever syntax emu8086 supports
    MOV DS, AX    ; Source segment address.
    
    MOV AX, 0800H 
    MOV ES, AX    ; Destination segment address.
    
    MOV AL, [NUM1]
    MOV ES:[0010H], AL
    MOV AL, [NUM2]
    MOV ES:[0011H], AL
    MOV AL, [NUM3]
    MOV ES:[0012H], AL
    MOV AL, [NUM4]
    MOV ES:[0013H], AL
    MOV AL, [NUM5]
    MOV ES:[0014H], AL
```

Or, when the NUM* values are known at write-time, you can use their immediate values:

```
.code            
        MOV AX, 0800H 
        MOV DS,AX
        MOV BYTE [0010H],22H ; NUM1
        MOV BYTE [0011H],00H ; NUM2
        MOV BYTE [0012H],35H ; NUM3
        MOV BYTE [0013H],71H ; NUM4
        MOV BYTE [0014H],03H ; NUM5
```

Another alternative is mem2mem copy using [MOVSB](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq):

```
.data    
    NUM0 DB 00H
    NUM1 DB 22H
    NUM2 DB 00H
    NUM3 DB 35H
    NUM4 DB 71H
    NUM5 DB 03H
.code            
    MOV AX, .data ; or whichever syntax emu8086 supports
    MOV DS, AX    ; Source segment address.
    MOV AX, 0800H 
    MOV ES, AX    ; Destination segment address.
    MOV SI,OFFSET NUM1 ; Source offset.
    MOV DI,0010H  ; Destination offset.
    MOV CX,5      ; Number of copied bytes.
    CLD           ; Direction of transfer.
    REP MOVSB     ; Copy CX bytes from DS:SI to ES:DI.
```

Comment: emu8086 uses MASM style, so `MOV AL, NUM1` correctly loads the byte at NUM1. You might want to change `MOV BYTE [0010H], 22H` into `MOV BYTE PTR [0010H], 22H` as required by MASM style.

Comment: What you said makes sense in my head. But when I tried to use your code the result at `0800:0010` has `01` `00` `F4` `00` `01` and that's not the original numbers given. Sorry if I missed something but the answer is appreciated.

Comment: @Coldcammey 0800:0010 is linear address 8010h (32784 in decimal). Is that the address that you are looking at? Also, this address is pretty low in memory; you could be overwriting parts of another program...

Comment: @SepRoland yes that is the adress I am looking at. I didn't know it was low on memory but the information planned to move there is pretty small I think.